# possible to config Git line-endings specific to repo?

Tags: git, github, newline, line-endings, lf

I am working on both Windows and Mac against a repo with origin on GitHub.

On GitHub, I want line-endings to be LF.

On Mac OS X, I want line-endings to be LF.

On Windows, I want line-endings to be CRLF -- except for a specific repo where I want LF.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that on windows you run

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

which will automatically translate to and from windows line endings

and then in specific repositories, which don't want conversion, you should run

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

as you will notice git config has a --global property which modifies your ~/.gitconfig ( or C:\Users\.gitconfig ) file.   Without this flag these settings are added to your repository.

See the [git reference manual](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace) for a further explanation